# Installing aurelia-materialize bridge

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to get the aurelia-materialize bridge plugin to work, and so far have been unable to do it with jspm, so I tried with webpack. I extracted the typescript-webpack skeleton into a folder, ran

```
npm install
```

then ran

```
npm install --save aurelia-materialize-bridge materialize-css
```

yet the install fails with error:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@2.1.0-beta.20
```

Any help getting this to work, or showing me any way to use materialize with aurelia would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this error is safe to ignore. Are you getting any errors while running the app?

Comment: It is indeed safe to ignore this error. The installaton doesn't fail either. I don't know why this is logged but it does no harm. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `npm install aurelia-materialize-bridge`
append`-g` or `--save` if needed

Make sure after installation it is saved under *jspm_packages/npm/*
If you save it in a different directory make sure it is loaded correctly in your *index.html*